# What is the probability of rolling 3 dice twice and getting the same configuration on both rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Case A) The dice are distinguishable.
Case B) The dice are not distinguishable.
This exercise is solven on my text book but I dont understand why the B) case is solved like it is. It use permutations and variations to get the favorable cases and then they divide by te variation of 6 elements taken 6 by 6.

$$
p2 = \frac{V_{6,3}\cdot P_{3} + V_{6,2}\cdot RP_{3}^{2,1,0}\cdot RP_{3}^{1,2,0} + V_{6,1}\cdot RP_{3}^{3,0,0}}{RV_{6,6}}
$$

That is the answer they give, and the solution is 83/3888. Can someone explain me why should I solve this this way and what is the real diference between the case A and case B?

Comment: If you have red, green and blue dice, are these outcomes different? (i) red 2, blue 3, green 5, (ii) red 3, blue 5, green 2.

Comment: @AnginaSeng no, that is part of the question, if the dice are different, the number of favorable cases is the same that it is when the dices are not different, but I dont understand why in mi text book it counts thhe favorable cases as a variation with repetitions of 6 elements taken 3 by 3, and when the dice are not different it count the different cases like that, in fact in my mind it the p2 numerator should be equal to RV6,3

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lost on the notations a bit. Can you explain what V, P, RP and RV are?

Comment: @SinTan1729 yes sorry, is the notation my text book uses and I'm from Spain. V is variations, P permutation, and the R means repetition so RV6,3 for example means a variaton of six elements taken 3 by 3 with repetitions. Th case of RP the three numbers over the P means the frequenci of each element, I mean,  the RP(3)^ 2,1,0 means that takes 3 elements and the frequency is the first element appears 2 times, second element 1time and the last one 0 times

Comment: @AnginaSeng I think the difference between the case 1 and case 2 is that when you get for example, 1, 4,3 in case A you only care about get 1,4,3 without thinking about which dice is numbered with which number, but in case B, you should take care about which dice is the one with each number. Sorry, I dont specify this in the question because I have just realice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the notation, but I can tell you how to solve the problem.

There are $6^3=216$ possible rolls.  In $6$ rolls, all three dice show the same number.  There are $6\cdot5\cdot3=90$ rolls where two of the dice are the same and the third different and $6\cdot5\cdot4=120$ rolls where all three numbers are different.

The probability that the second person rolls the same as the first is $$\frac6{216}\frac1{216}+\frac{90}{216}\frac3{216}+\frac{120}{216}\frac{6}{216}=\frac{996}{216^2}=\frac{83}{3888}$$

In each term, the first factor is the probability that the first player rolls a result of a particular type, and the second factor is the probability that the second player matches the roll.

Does this make sense?  Feel free to ask if it doesn't.

Comment: thank you, in the way you see the problem is much more eassy to understand. This way the solution is the same but I understand it. How have you reach your solution? Just by looking for favorable cases?

Comment: @DaríoPérez It's just the law of total probability.  Partition the first event into disjoint cases, add up the probability of success in each case.

Comment: I undestand the law, but I think I'm extremly bad at counting probabilities, How could I improve this hability? I mean, It looks easy when you do it, how can I reach this level? Sorry if my question exced your confidence, do not feel forced to answer.

Comment: @DaríoPérez The only thing I can suggest is practice.  Do lots of problems.